# How to return value from a screen to previous screen on ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, return-value

I have experience with android but really new on ios. on Android, I can use startActivityForResult() to navigate from screen A to screen B. And then, when B is closed, the system will notify the screen A at a callback method to do something (e.g. get returned values, refresh data,...)

What I want to ask here is that: is there any way to register a call back function that will be call when the screen B is closed? How to return the data from screen B to screen A?

I know  that I can declare a public property then set value to it from screen B. But, I think this way may make my source code complicated and less security. (i.e. I don't want to open property to other screen for assessing).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the delegate pattern for this.

(Take a look at UITextField, UITableView, etc... they all use this pattern).

You set up a delegate property on the second view called something like...

```
SecondViewDelegate
```

And in the protocol you give it a method like...

```
- (void)secondViewDidSelectValue:(NSString*)selectedValue;
```

Then in the first view you make it the delegate of the second view.

There are many resources about this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a better way to do that. It is called delegation. In the View Controller you are dismissing you create a `@protocol` and an `@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ProtocolName> delegate;`. You set this value from the previous View Controller:`secondVC.delegate = self`. It will be like a Java Interface. Then when your second View Controller disappears you call the delegate method (e.g. in `viewWillDisappear:`).

Hope this makes sense!